# Open Venmo from Another App iOS

Tags: ios, swift, url, venmo

I know it's possible to open other apps from within an app using URL schemes, but to my knowledge those URLs need to be created by the developers. I'm trying to allow users of my app to open the Venmo app. Is this possible to do? I couldn't find any "public" URL schemes for Venmo. Ideally my app would be able to open Venmo directly to a specific users' profile. I'm using Swift.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the SDK/API is not available to new developers. Venmo closed it last year: https://techcrunch.com/2016/02/26/how-not-to-run-a-platform/

I'm looking for a way around this, so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Venmo has [an SDK](https://github.com/venmo/venmo-ios-sdk), and it allows you to open the app and go straight to a transaction.

From the SDK source it's possible to reverse-engineer the URL scheme but I would recommend not doing that, and it might not even work. I would suggest just implementing the SDK and let it handle it, apparently it will even call back your app when finished.

Venmo does have a page that shows you how to create a "suggest payments" link with a scheme. https://developer.venmo.com/paymentlinks I assume that iOS would direct users to the app but you would have to check. Good luck.

Comment: Ok I tried this and it is a good work around. I think I'll use this.

Comment: great workaround at the moment because Venmo hasn't opened up their API to new developers. It will direct you from your current app, to a safari page with a button to pay in the venmo app, then if the user clicks this button it willl say "open in venmo" and then will open the venmo app to the specified page. Not perfect, but good enough for me for now.

Answer (score 4):

## Please note that the correct answer here is no longer correct

Venmo and Paypal had shut down their SDK  service for new merchants. All their SDK's becomes legacy and there is no news as of now for them to be back.

From their official site, they are suggesting you to use a their party SDK called [Brain Tree](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/ios/v4). If you want to do transactions, that should be your only options for now.

You **can** reverse engineer their current legacy SDK to make your app switch to their apps, but that's it. Without app key or app secret, I don't believe you can open a payment page to a specific user and get a call back to indicate if the payment goes through or not

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can open other apps. Its called mobile deep linking 
Here you can find the good article for the same. 
https://www.programmableweb.com/news/how-to-implement-deep-linking-ios/how-to/2015/07/14

For your question about venmo app, you will need to use their SDK to open venmo app and accept payment 
Here is the link for venmo iOS SDK
https://github.com/venmo/venmo-ios-sdk